# I need help input a file in chunks into mmap

Tags: c, mmap

I am trying to use mmap to read a file using chunks of 1024.

Here is a code snippit....

```
numberOfBuffers = filesize / buffersize;
if (filesize % buffersize) 
{
  numberOfBuffers++;       
}

for (i = 0; i < numberOfBuffers; i++) {
    if((map = mmap(NULL, buffersize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, i * buffersize)) == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("map failed");
    }

    if(munmap(map, buffersize) == -1) {
            perror("unmap failed");
    }
 }
```

I am getting an 'illegal argument' error on the second iteration.

I'm looking to understand mmap and for help on how to iterate over mmap with a defined buffer size.

Comment: "...appears to be..." - don't guess, make sure please.

Comment: I think this `if (numberOfBuffers % buffersize) `  should be `if (fileSize % buffersize) `

Comment: Sorry... I had a print statement after the first if statement and it only printed once then I got the 'illegal argument' error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `mmap` man page:

> offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE).

Page size on a lot if systems (notably x86) is 4k (4096 bytes). So the first call will succeed (with offset 0), but the second call will fail (offset 1024 is not valid).

Try changing your chunk size to 4096 (or whatever the page size is on your platform, or better, use `sysconf` to get that information).

Comment: That was it, once I used 4096 or multiples it is working. Thank for the help. I understand this a bit more now.